# correct value of maxRequestWorkers

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, threads, performance-tuning

I've set the value of maxRequestWorkers to 4000 in the apache2.conf file. 
But when i run the apache2buddy perl script the reported value is 150 for maxrequestworkers. How does apache2buddy perl script calcualate the maxrequestWorkers (can a perl expert break down the section in the perl script)? is there another way to verify the MaxRequestWorkers via a command line? Are there any other files where this value can be defined besides apache2.conf ? ( environment is docker container in ec2 instanace running ubuntu . )

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html),
section "MaxRequestWorkers Directive":

> For non-threaded servers (i.e., prefork), MaxRequestWorkers translates
>   into the maximum number of child processes that will be launched to
>   serve requests. The default value is 256; to increase it, you must
>   also raise ServerLimit.
>
> For threaded and hybrid servers (e.g. event or worker)
>   MaxRequestWorkers restricts the total number of threads that will be
>   available to serve clients. For hybrid MPMs the default value is 16
>   (ServerLimit) multiplied by the value of 25 (ThreadsPerChild).
>   Therefore, to increase MaxRequestWorkers to a value that requires more
>   than 16 processes, you must also raise ServerLimit.

You must ensure that the value of ServerLimit multiplied by ThreadsPerChild
is at least 4000, before setting maxRequestWorkers to that value.

Beware of increasing the limits beyond the capabilities of your hardware,
specifically regarding CPU and RAM.

For information on calculating these limits see for example
[this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/796983/18736).